# Clearing contents of TextField using setText does not work in AWT

Tags: java, awt

I am having problems clearing contents of `TextField` in AWT using `setText()` method. Apparently, `setText("")` does not clear the contents of the `TextField` on pressing the 'Reset' button. Here's my program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class form extends Frame
{

    Label lbl = new Label("Name:");
    TextField tf = new TextField();
    Button btn = new Button("Reset");

    public form()
    {
        tf.setColumns(20);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });


        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
               tf.setText("");  //Problem occurs here. This does not clear the contents of the text field on pressing the 'Reset' button.

            }
        });


        add(lbl);
        add(tf);
        add(btn);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(400,100);
        setVisible(true);
        setTitle("Form");

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new form();
    }

}
```

Can someone please tell me where I went wrong or suggest an alternative? Thanks.

Comment: Works for me as excepted. Type something click on reset and the field is empty.

Comment: I see the problem as well. What version of Java are you using? I seem to remember seeing this as a known bug, let me see if I can find that...

Comment: I use both Java 7 update 65 and Java 8 update 11 and the problem seems to persist in both

Comment: Why use AWT components rather than Swing?  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon AWT.

Comment: @AndrewThompson , thanks for the link. I was supposed to use AWT only for creating a form application as my requirement and hence the components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see the problem as well using Java 8u11. I seem to remember this being filed as a known bug, but I can't seem to find it now.

A solution that works for me is to add an intermediate step:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   tf.setText(" ");  
   tf.setText("");
}
```

I'm not sure why this is necessary, I think it's a bug with the setText() function specifically ignoring empty Strings. If somebody finds the filed bug there would be more information there.

Comment: Thanks. This quickfix works. If you find any information on this bug, please post the link here.

Answer (score -1):

Add space in setText("  ") in function and see if it works. But there after there will be one space.

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer posted 4 years ago? Especially "see if it works"? OP already confirmed it works.